# Cut Texture into Mesh

Tags: materials

I want to cut my texture into my mesh.

[image]

So I want those grey Flower Like Texture to actually be in the Mesh itself.

---

I want to add carvings like this

[image]

Comment: Select your object, press `tab` to go into *Edit Mode* and the press `a` to select all faces and then `u` to unwrap.

Comment: No I want to cut into the Mesh with the Texture not unwrap the Mesh onto the Mesh

Comment: Are you ok with "faking" the engraving using a bump map?

Comment: do you want to give thickness to your mesh? if not, you could just use the image as mask to make the plane transparent, if yes you can convert your image to svg then convert the svg to mesh

Comment: No i wanna literally cut into the mesh and give it depth, maybe even height So like extruding the mesh with the texture

Comment: convert your image to svg in an image eidtor (Photoshop, etc), import into Blender, convert to mesh, in Edit mode select all and press X > Limited Dissolve, extrude

Comment: You can experiment with @Nic's script he posted as answer, this should work for you, just make some adjustments to it. The mesh output looks pretty with your image design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once ran into the same problem, so I wrote a little script making an mesh from the image depending on pixel value. It is based around three functions, but also has some more funcitionalities. It is simple but slow. Strongly recommend to use decimate modifier after conversion.

```
        ### DESCRIPTION  ###
    #Convert an Image to an into an STL with local height analog to its colors/grayscale. Useful for Stamp making or PCB printing on Resin Printer.
    #when happy with the result use the solidify modifier to make the part 3d printable.

    #It is simple but relatively slow. (Runtime Linear to Pixelcount, 2 Facees in STL per Pixel!)
    #WARNING:Large images will take a long time to compute, blender will be "unresponsive" during the calculation.

    #If you want to check the Progress of the calculation go to "Window=>Toggle System Console" in the main menue(top left)
    #Works only on specific datatypes such as JPG and PNG.

    ### IMPORTS ###
    import bpy
    import numpy as np
    from mathutils import Vector

    ### PARAMETERS ###
    useColor="g" #Options: r=Red, g=green, b=blue, g=grayscale, a=Alpha(=Transparency)
    invertImage=False # for convinience
    exportMeshName="DepthObject" #Name of the exported object.
    pixelsPerUnit=10 # Image resolution. In STLs Units are not defined, so chose one you and your slicing software like.
    desiredHeight=1 #enter value in the same unit
    Offset=0

    #Load the image: Option 1:
    image_path=r"C:\Users\nicol\OneDrive\Desktop\Bild Nic.jpg"
    image = bpy.data.images.load(image_path)

    # Option 2:read the Image in the Blender GUI in the UV Editing Tab, 
    # =>creating a blender image object before executing script and call it instead of image path,
    # uncomment line below to use this approach. 
    #image=bpy.data.objects["Beispielbild"] 

    #automated post processing Option
    usemodifiers=False # Also select modifiers by uncommenting desired lines in "MODIFIERS" section.


    ### HELPER FUNCTIONS ###
    def img2array(img,**kwargs):
        invertImg=kwargs.get("invert",False)
        w, h = img.size
        pixels = np.empty(w * h *4, dtype=np.float32)
        img.pixels.foreach_get(pixels)
        imgArr=pixels.reshape((h, w, 4))#w,h swapped, because row, column!=x,y
        if invertImg:
            imgArr=1-imgArr
        return imgArr

    def extractGray(arr):
        rgb=arr[:,:,:3]
        gray=np.sum(rgb,axis=2)/3
        return gray

    def extractColor(arr,color):
        colors={"r":0,"g":1,"b":2,"a":3}
        if colors.get(color):
            return arr[:,:,colors.get(color)]
        else:
            return extractGray(arr)  


    def printProgress(idx,total):    
        percentage=round(idx/total*100)
        lastPercentage=round((idx-1)/total*100)
        if (not percentage%10) and lastPercentage!=percentage:
            print(f"{percentage} % done")
            
    def makeSurf(imgarr,**kwargs): # main function
        res=kwargs.get("res",1)
        zscale=kwargs.get("zscale",1)
        offset=kwargs.get("offset",0)
        name=kwargs.get("name","Surface")
        print("Creating Vertecies (1/3)")
        verts=createVerts(imgarr,res,zscale,offset)
        print("Creating Faces (2/3)")        
        faces=createFaces(imgarr) 
        print("Adding Mesh Object (3/3")        
        makeObjFromMeshdata(name,verts,[],faces)
        
    def createVerts(imgarr,res,zscale,offset):
        verts=[]
        w,h=imgarr.shape    
        for idx in range(w):
            for idy in range(h):    
                verts.append(Vector([idx*res,idy*res,zscale*imgarr[idx,idy]+offset]))
            printProgress(idx,w)
        return verts    

    def createFaces(imgarr):
        faces=[]
        w,h=imgarr.shape   
        for idx in range(w-1):
            for idy in range(h-1):
                faces.append([(idx)*h+idy,(idx)*h+idy+1,(idx+1)*h+idy+1,(idx+1)*h+idy])
            printProgress(idx,w-1) 
        return faces    
            
    def makeObjFromMeshdata(name,verts,edges,faces):       
        mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)  # add the new mesh
        obj = bpy.data.objects.new(mesh.name, mesh)
        col = bpy.data.collections.get("Collection")
        col.objects.link(obj)
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
        mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)

    ### MAIN PROGRAMM ###
    if __name__=="__main__":
        a=img2array(image,invert=invertImage)
        colorarr=extractColor(a,useColor)
        makeSurf(colorarr,name=exportMeshName,zscale=desiredHeight,res=1/pixelsPerUnit,offset=Offset)


    ### MODIFIERS ###
        if usemodifiers:
            pass
            #print("Using Modifiers")
            #bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='DECIMATE')
            #bpy.context.object.modifiers["Decimate"].decimate_type = 'UNSUBDIV'
            #bpy.context.object.modifiers["Decimate"].iterations = 1
            #bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Decimate")

            #bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='CORRECTIVE_SMOOTH')
            #bpy.context.object.modifiers["CorrectiveSmooth"].use_only_smooth = True
            #bpy.context.object.modifiers["CorrectiveSmooth"].iterations = 12
            #bpy.context.object.modifiers["CorrectiveSmooth"].factor = 0.9
            #bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="CorrectiveSmooth")

            #bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='TRIANGULATE')
            #bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Triangulate")

            #bpy.context.object.modifiers["Decimate"].decimate_type = 'DISSOLVE'
            #bpy.context.object.modifiers["Decimate"].angle_limit = 0.1



            #bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SOLIDIFY')
            #bpy.context.object.modifiers["Solidify"].thickness = zscale*1.2
            #bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Solidify")
```

Comment: I tried your script, quite interesting it works.

Comment: Happy to hear that :)
Another option might be to use your Image as a normal map, using it via a displacement modifier. But I was not able to get that running.